# Getting string from one android device and sending to other devices

Tags: java, android

I try to develop an android app and I got stuck on this problem.

I want to send two string values(longitude, latitude) from one android device to other android devices that have the same app. From researching online, **my understanding is that the android devices sends the two strings to a server and then I can use google gcm to send those strings to other devices(I think).** Maybe the server can run java and I can write some program to do something with the data it receives later.

I have successfully obtained the location data from the android device, **but got stuck on sending this location from android phone to a server on my computer.** My professor told me that I can make my computer a server. Before connecting android and my mac, I tried connecting two computers. I successfully connected my imac and macbook using Socket&SocketServer examples found at the bottom of http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_networking.htm. It took a long time because I didn't know I had to remove the firewall.

So I found another example to connect an android to a computer using Socket at http://lakjeewa.blogspot.ca/2012/03/simple-client-server-application-for.html and tried it. Although, two computers could be connected, android won't connect to my computer. I think the problem is in the code

```
client = new Socket(serverName, port);
```

I tried many things for serverName such as the computer's ip address that start with 192.168, "localhost", 10.0.2.2, http:/myIpAdressFoundByGoogling, "myComputerName.local" but none worked. What's the problem here? The android device does not have a sim card and it is connected to the same wifi as the computer. I should have XAAMPP? (I just found about this last night) and learn php first? I am completely lost what to do with server.

I ended up here because I was thinking I can test and develop the app using a computer as a server and when I finish developing, I can get a server(like amazon web services, I am not sure yet) and replace the server location in the code, and copy and paste the server java code. **Can I do this?** maybe Google App Engine is a viable solution for my problem?

The client code is...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Socket client;
private PrintWriter printwriter;
private EditText textField;
private Button button;
private String message;
private int port = 5555;
private String serverName = "192.168.?????"; I think this is where the problem is


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            message = textField.getText().toString();
            textField.setText("");

            try {
                // connect with server
                client = new Socket(serverName, port);
                printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),
                        true);
                printwriter.write(message);

                printwriter.flush();
                printwriter.close();
                client.close();

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

The server code is...

```
public class main {

private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
private static Socket clientSocket;
private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
private static String message;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int port = 5555;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("could not listen on port: " + port);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("server started listening to the port " + port);

    while (true) {

    try {
        // accept the client connection
        clientSocket =serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("someone connected to the server");
        inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());

        //get the client meesage
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        message = bufferedReader.readLine();

        System.out.println(message);
        inputStreamReader.close();
        clientSocket.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("problem in reading the message");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably unable to connect your android device to your computer wither because there is some configuration problem or something is wrong in the code at one end. I have previously successfully sent messages from an android device to a "server" that ran on my laptop, I did this with the Socket and ServerSocket technique very similar to the example you linked to. So this is more than possible. There is no need to install additional software on either side (Java run-time is enough).

If both the computer and the android device are connected on the same wifi network you should use the internal LAN address. If you are running this on the android emulator and you want to connect to the host computer (the computer that runs the emulator) you can use 10.0.2.2 or just the computers address (this works also). What port are you using? Is this port open on your router settings, firewalls, etc.?

You do not have to learn PHP or App Engine to do what you are trying to do. You can, and these will also allow you to do this (I have no experience with App Engine but I am pretty sure it can). As for the PHP you will need to install XAAMPP on your machine to be able to use this as a server.

Another question is: If you plan to actually put this on a server you should check what kind of server you will have/need. A simple hosting package will most likely not allow you to run your own java code there but will probably allow you to run PHP scripts, for example.

If you post the networking code of both the client and the server, you will be able to get more accurate feedback than just my general and top-level answer.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions/crashes? or does the code execute fine and just the message isn't being sent?

Comment: I just get "unfortunately, your application has stopped." FATAL EXCEPTION, android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException and other red lines in LogCat.

Comment: Alright! I know the problem. Your networking code is in your listener, and listeners are run on the main thread, however you MUST not do networking on the main thread, what you need to do is this: In the listener start a new Thread or AsyncTask and move the networking code there...

Answer (score 0):

I am taking an Android development class at the moment as well. I think you should look into Parse, it is a free service that provides all the backend server stuff for you, for free. We have been using it in out app. Once you get the hang of how the callbacks work it's very easy to use. Otherwise I would recommend looking into some kind of web framework like ruby on rails, and write your backend in that. You can deploy all that onto heroku and then assess your backend with android async talker.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to connect to your server via a webservice and then consume that webservice in your application? I've successfully connected my device to my laptop doing this.

Take a look at this guys tutorial:

http://android.programmerguru.com/android-webservice-example/

I believe this is the best practice when communicating device to server.